# multiple type errors -- confused --- adding css with jquery to checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, typeerror

Ok. super confused. I tried to run my code and got multiple type errors, and I am not entirely sure what they even mean, exactly.

What I am trying to do is create a grocery list, with checkboxes, and make it so that when a checkbox is checked, then it adds the css class "text-decoration: line-through" and when it is unchecked, it removes the line through. Help? Thank you :)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Function.camelCase (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.css (jquery.min.js:2)
    at init.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.access (jquery.min.js:2)
    at init.css (jquery.min.js:2)
    at strikeout (check.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:18)
```

here is my code:

js file:

```
function strikeout(){
var checkedbox = document.getElementsByName("grocery").checked;
if (checkedbox == true){
  $("checkedbox").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
} else {
  $("checkedbox").css();
}
}
```

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body><form>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
<ul><li><input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="milk">Milk</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="butter">butter</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="eggs">eggs</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="eggs">cheese</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="coffee">coffee</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" onclick="strikeout()">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="check.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There must be a problem with this line `var checkedbox = document.getElementsByName("grocery").checked;
` because document.getElementsByName will return array of elements.

Comment: One more problem here too: `$("checkedbox")` 

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://jsbin.com/baharitopa/edit?html,output ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your code and got it working with jQuery, since you're including it on your page.

Since you have multiple checkboxes, `checked` needs to be tested on each element in a *loop*. `document.getElementsByName("grocery").checked` was coming up `undefined`, then you were checking to see if it was true, hence the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` error.

```js
function strikeout() {
  var $inputs = $('input');

  $inputs.each(function() {
    var $input = $(this),
        isChecked = $input.is(':checked');

    if (isChecked) {
      $input.parent().css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    } else {
      $input.parent().css('text-decoration', 'none');
    }
  });
}

$('button').on('click', strikeout);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="milk">Milk</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="butter">butter</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="eggs">eggs</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="eggs">cheese</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="coffee">coffee</li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ronak that you are going to run into issues with `checkedbox` as a selector, as no such element exists -- *however*, looking at your stack trace it looks like the issue causing the error is at line 6 where you call `.css()` with no argument:

```
$("checkedbox").css();
```

Looking at the [.css documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) there is no support for such a signature-- it is probably looking for an argument and finding none.  You can even just drop that line wholesale into the console and it will fire the same error-- and if you add appropriate arguments it run without throwing an error:

```
$("checkedbox").css('color', 'red');
```

Perhaps review what you are intending that line to accomplish.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, selector `$("checkedbox")` mean that jQuery select all elements which have tag `<checkedbox></checkedbox>` and that's why error happen. XD

Then ... if you want to change css on checbox change (e.g. when user click the checkbox), then you should create jQuery `.on()` script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //when <input> with name "grocery" clicked/changed ...
    $("input[name=grocery]").on('click change',function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) { //check if checked
            $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
        } else {
            $(this).css("text-decoration", ""); //to reset the css
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this help. Good luck! :)

**Addition:**

You can also do it like this:

```
    $(document.body).on('click change','input[name=grocery]',function() {
```

This mean event handler will bind to body instead of per element. In case your checkboxes are loaded/created dynamically e.g. using ajax. ;)

Comment: lmao omg >.> sorry, I make the silliest mistakes sometimes (referring to the $("checkedbox") >.> wow oops. haha. thank you

Comment: ahaha, no problem xD

Answer (score 1):

I just made it smaller by using pseudo selector on input. The results are same, you can also use filter after selecting all the checkboxes e.g.

```js
$('input').filter(function(index){
return $(this).is(":selected");
}).each(function(){
$(this).parent().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
});
```

And here is working example:

```js
$(function(){
function strikeout() {
  $('input').parent().css("text-decoration", "none");
$('input:checked').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
});
}

$('button').on('click', strikeout);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="milk">Milk</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="butter">butter</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="eggs">eggs</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="eggs">cheese</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="grocery" value="coffee">coffee</li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your JS part.

```
function strikeout(){

   //Clear the line through
   $("[name='grocery']").each(function(){
     $(this).parent().css("text-decoration", "none")
   });

   //Fetch the Checked items
   var checkedbox = $("[name='grocery']:checked");

  //Add Line through to the <li>
  checkedbox.each(function(){
    $(this).parent().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
  });
}
```